Is it possible to skip the warning screen on a locked bootloader running custom firmware?
This question is from a malicious viewpoint to see if its possible that it happened in my case
I have got answers before that if my bootloader is locked then a factory reset(/even reflash stock rom) is the way to ensure its clean, how true is this and to what extent?
I was thinking of hardware key attestation(/binwalk and hexdump) to detect it but it is hard and i have no idea how to remove it(may require replacement/reverse engineering)?
My unlockable phones keeps getting hacked(local media leak, keylogger and sim issues) but shows no sign of compromise so i suspect malicious firmware
The reason i suspect its the bootloader because it didnt happen on my phone which didnt have an unlockable bootloader(phone 1) and happened on the phone which had an unlockable bootloader(phone2)
(My friend had borrowed both my phones for less than a day and i had noticed there was a spy app in phone 1 and nothing bad in the other phone which had an unlockable bootloader(phone2)) but since it shows symptoms of getting hacked have factory reset and reflashed the stock rom multiple times with no success
Does the user-settable root of trust even matter in this case or can the entire thing be bypassed itself by backdoored firmware or such? What are my options in this case?
The reason i post this is because it happened for the second time in my 3rd phone (which has an unlockable bootloader and which i had not left alone for more than 4hrs) and i have tossed both previous phones due to age
I suspect an evil maid attack and i have not found much info about it on android in google so i am curious to know more

Never did it but it is possible to unlock a bootloader install a custom ROM and also updating the signing keys and then re-lock the bootloader. Updating the signing keys is AFIK only supported by a subset of devices. Also relocking the bootloader is pretty dangerous as it may brick your device is you made a small mistake. In my understanding such a relocked bootloader should not show the warning sign.

Previous question (already deleted), possibly for additional context: Understanding different types of Persistent Evil Maid Attacks

@AndrewT. I find this to be more accurate but it isnt answered fully https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/122188/android-rooting-and-evil-maid-attacks
